# Run small code snippet run with jdk 5 and rest of code with jdk 6

Tags: java, java-6, java-5

Is it possible to run small code snippet run with jdk 5 and rest of code with jdk 6?

Have one code which is working fine with jdk 5. I am going to change it as per jdk 6 but currently don't have time to do this. So is there any way to execute 4 lines with jdk 5.

Seems like funny but it's required.... please suggest me....

Comment: why are you trying to do that? JDK 5 and JDK6 can run the same code and are compatible.

Comment: What is the code that is causing you a problem?

Comment: *"Seems like funny but it's required"*  What seems less funny is that you thought the reasons were not worth mentioning.  At least 3 people think different.

Comment: As you can run Java 1.0 byte code on Java 7, what sort of migration from Java 5.0 to Java 6 are you doing?

Comment: It's not about byte code. Trying to create one html file using jasperreport_4.1.2.1.jar. same code same setup is working fine with jdk 5. And gives me distorted UI with jdk 6(html file which generated with jasperreport jar). It's about File handling....

Answer (score 2):

Anything developed with JDK5 will be compatible with JDK 6 (from a source code perspective) and will run on a JRE 6 JVM. Note the distinction between source-code/compilation and the actual running of the resultant bytecode. So I don't think you need to do anything other than compile/run with JDK/JRE 6.

Comment: Trying to create one html file using jasperreport_4.1.2.1.jar. same code same setup is working fine with jdk 5. And gives me distorted UI with jdk 6(html file which generated with jasperreport jar).